# Proper way for angular to communicate in spring boot with token

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, jwt, access-token

In spring boot i have set up JWT in spring security with 2 API.

1. API login it will response a token.
2. API get the user information base on token subject sample email

Then in angular, when user success login will put the token in query parameter or in session storage or in cookie to be use in Home page.
When the component is excecuted , in order to get the user information at the backend i will use this token to identify who is the user then return its detail
to be populated in the form in angular. Which mean the request will be base on token to the backend.

Would like to ask for senior dev for proper way for security purpose.